# How to calculate the number of combinations that will add to a specific total

Tags: mathematical-statistics, combinatorics

If I have for example 3 variables, and I need them to add to specific total, say 6, how do I calculate the number of combinations that will add to 6. Like 1+1+4=6 and 1+4+1=6 and 2+2+2=6 and 1+2+3=6 etc.

Is there a formula I can use? What if I am using say 10 variables with ranges from say 1 to 1000 and the total is for example 8063?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to find the number of integer solutions to the problem:
$$x_1+...+x_k=n, \ \ \ x_i\geq a$$
The general formula for number of solutions is $ {n-ak+k-1 \choose k-1}$. For three variable case, and positive integers as in your example, we have $k=3,a=1,n=6$, which yields ${5 \choose 2}=10$ solutions. Specifically, they are $\{(1,1,4),(1,4,1),(4,1,1),(2,2,2),\underbrace{(1,2,3)}_{6 \ \text{permutations}}\}$.

The logic is simple. Let's say you want to solve $x_1+x_2+x_3=6,\ \ x_i\geq 0$. Each solution corresponds to a permutation of chracters `||111111`, e.g. `11|111|1` corresponds to $x_1=2,x_2=3,x_3=1$. So, we'll use $n$ number of $1$'s and $k-1$ number of separators, which yields a total of ${n+k-1 \choose k-1}$ permutations. A small extension is adding non-zero constraints, e.g. $x_i\geq 1$. Then, we first throw $1$'s into the variables, and allocate the remaining 1's. We can work out the formula for the general case, following the example.

Comment: Could you provide a reference for the general formula you post or derive it.

Comment: I've added some explanation. I didn't get it from anywhere.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much. You explained it very well.